# How to create a unique link to some page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to generate an unique link, so that when user clicks on it, they end up on some page/**action**. However, they can't go directly to that page/**action** just by typing a simple URL on address bar.

How can this be achieved in Rails?

Comment: Just curious what's the usecase for this? Usually if you want to restrict information, this is usually handled through some sort of login/authentication system.

Comment: @the12 For example beta access to some site. Users submit a request and then admin emails them with a link that can be used to access signup page.

Comment: you could just add some parameter to the url you're sending out and if the person coming in has that token then display the page, else redirect them somewhere else

Comment: @Rocco nice suggestion, but what if I want that link to be unique for each email- i.e. can’t be shared with others?

Comment: A simple solution would be to base64 encode the email address and add that as a URL query parameter. Or, you could salt it to make it more obscure.

Comment: Then you'd need some concept of users. Say you didn't and just had a list of tokens you'd given out pointing to booleans saying if they'd been used or not. If someone clicked in once, you'd mark the token as used, so if the person ever tried to come back they wouldn't be able to get in. You need to know WHO used it to allow that

Comment: @CarlMarkham But how can I recognize that query parameter on action side since its value can be random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use something like a database of tokens and an expiry for that token.

```
# url
url/items?token=12345

def index
  token = Token.find_by_token(params[:token])
  if token && token.expiry > Time.now
   #do something
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Downvote because the question itself isn't a valid SO question. There isn't enough information to give a proper answer and no attempt seems to have been made by OP to attempt to solve the issue

Comment: @CarlMarkham what if I don't have any clue as to how to implement it?

Comment: Updated. However, if you're already using Devise you can use [Devise confirmable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb)

Comment: Looks like what I need! Thank you!